# Column filter in Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, business-intelligence, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I m new to quicksight, I am trying to filter column in the quicksight, same way we do in excel.but i m getting blanks or not able to find how to filter.

[Want to see only family which has gap point value as review,i.e the filter should only show (d,f) and not any other value or blanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4babB.png)

please help !!

[Want to see only family which has gap point value as review,i.e the filter should only show (d,f) and not any other value or blanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4babB.png)

please help !!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to filter a visualization, you need to:

- Click the visualization to select it.
- Click the "Filter" button on the left of the screen.
- Click "Add filter"
- Select the column you want to use for the filter (in this case "gap point value").
- Edit the filter, and select the value "REVIEW", then click "Apply".

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/add-a-filter-data-prep.html